# Create an event with conference using python and Google Calendar API creates the event but not the conference

Tags: python-3.x, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create an event using Google Calendar API in Python 3. I also want to generate a Google Meet conference link for the event. I am using the documentations provided here:

- https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python
- https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#conferenceData
- https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events

The event is created without a problem. However, it is missing the conference link. My code so far is as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path
from pickle import load
from pickle import dump
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from uuid import uuid4
from typing import Dict, List
from oauth2client import file, client, tools


class EventPlanner:

    def __init__(self, guests: Dict[str, str], schedule: Dict[str, str]):
        guests = [{"email": email} for email in guests.values()]
        service = self._authorize()
        self.event_states = self._plan_event(guests, schedule, service)

    @staticmethod
    def _authorize():
        scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
        credentials = None
        token_file = Path("./calendar_creds/token.pickle")

        if token_file.exists():
            with open(token_file, "rb") as token:
                credentials = load(token)

        if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
            if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
                credentials.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('calendar_creds/credentials.json', scopes)
                credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            with open(token_file, "wb") as token:
                dump(credentials, token)

        calendar_service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials)

        return calendar_service

    @staticmethod
    def _plan_event(attendees: List[Dict[str, str]], event_time, service: build):
        event = {"summary": "test meeting",
                 "start": {"dateTime": event_time["start"]},
                 "end": {"dateTime": event_time["end"]},
                 "attendees": attendees,
                 "conferenceData": {"createRequest": {"requestId": f"{uuid4().hex}",
                                                      "conferenceSolutionKey": {"type": "hangoutsMeet"}}},
                 "reminders": {"useDefault": True}
                 }
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId="primary", sendNotifications=True, body=event, conferenceDataVersion=1).execute()

        return event


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plan = EventPlanner({"test_guest": "test.guest@gmail.com"}, {"start": "2020-07-31T16:00:00",
                                                                          "end": "2020-07-31T16:30:00"})
    print(plan.event_states)
```

I suspect that the problem is with where I have passed `conferenceDataVersion` but the docs are not exactly clear about where it has to be passed other than that it must be passed. I also tried putting it in the body of the event or in `createRequest`. It always creates the event but not the conference. Unfortunately, I could not find anything about this online anywhere. Maybe I'm actually that bad at searching, but I have been testing different things and searching for a solution for several days! If anyone knows what I am missing, I will truly appreciate their assistance.

Comment: I think that your script can create the conference link. From this situation, I thought that I might misunderstand about your goal. So can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for helping me again! The goal is to create an event which also includes a google meet link. The problem is that it does create the event, but without the google meet link. Including the `createRequest` in the event body has no effect. If I remove it, the outcome would be the same. When you say you think the script can create the conference link, is it a guess or does it work for you when you run it? Also, do you have a working example? If you do, do you mind if I ask you to share it please? I couldn't find even a single example online!

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your script, when I tested it, I could confirm that the conference link can be included in the created event. So I asked about your detail goal. But from your replying, I think that my understanding of your goal is correct. So I have to replicate your situation from your script. But in the current stage, I cannot replicate your issue. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike You are the best! So when you confirmed that it works for you, I realized that the problem is not the code! I started looking into other things like my account's configurations and what not. It turns out, the problem was with the token file generated by the API. I removed it and had it generate again and the problem is solved! I wish they had mentioned something about it in the docs. The docs are really half backed! And now I think the script above is literally the only example available online at this time!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Tanaike, I found what was the problem. The token which is generated the first time the API is authenticated is very specific. The problem I was having turned out to be just with that. As soon as I removed the token and had it get generated again, the problem was solved. That being said, I have no idea why the problem appeared in the first place. I will update the response if I find the reason behind it. But for now, if you are having the same problem, just remove the token and regenerate it.

Comment: I have the same problem and I recreated the `token.pickle` file without success.

My SCOPE is also `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`

I'm using a consumer account instead of a GSuite account. Don't know if that matters? What type of account were you using?

Comment: I got it. `conferenceDataVersion` needs to be passed as a parameter of the `insert` function. Not as a payload.

Answer (score 0):

1. With this code we can create the conference (Google meet link) for me  it works

```
    "conferenceData": {
        "createRequest": {
            "requestId": "SecureRandom.uuid"
        }
    }
```