# Why Google Calendar API accepting request body with conference details but not creating any conference link in response?

Tags: javascript, authentication, axios, google-calendar-api

I was trying to create an event with a conference meeting but when I tried with the below code I got the respective console log.

I also found some references but none of them worked.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167260246

[Create an event with conference using python and Google Calendar API creates the event but not the conference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63236108/create-an-event-with-conference-using-python-and-google-calendar-api-creates-th)

I am using React Native and I also used Google Authentication like this which is working pretty perfectly:

```
const configureGoogleSingin = async () => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      androidClientId:
        'some-id',
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
    });
  };

  const continueWithGoogle = async () => {
    GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices()
      .then(hasPlayService => {
        if (hasPlayService) {
          GoogleSignin.signIn()
            .then(userInfo => {
              // console.log(userInfo);
              checkAuthenticationOnBE(userInfo.user);
            })
            .catch(e => {
              console.log('ERROR IS: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
            });
        }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('ERROR IS: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
      });
  };
```

My code is like this:

```
const conferenceData = {
      // 'allowedConferenceSolutionTypes': ['hangoutsMeet'],
      'createRequest': {
        'requestId': `meet-${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}`,
        'conferenceSolutionKey': {
          'type': 'hangoutsMeet',
        },
      },
    };

    const event = {
      'summary': 'ShopOnLive Meeting',
      'description': "I want to buy something.",
      'start': {
        'dateTime': meetDateTime.toISOString(),
        'timeZone': Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone // current timeZone
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': moment(meetDateTime).add(40, 'minutes').toISOString(),
        'timeZone': Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone // current timeZone
      },
      'conferenceDataVersion': 1,
      'conferenceData': conferenceData,
      'organizer': {
        'email': 'sumit@shoponline.in',
      },
      "attendees": [
        // {
        //   "email": shop.user.email,
        //   "displayName": "Store Owner",
        //   "organizer": false,
        //   "self": true,
        // },
        // {
        //   "email": userEmail,
        //   "displayName": "Client",
        //   "organizer": false,
        //   "self": true,
        // },
      ],
    }

    console.log(event);

    if(!provider_token){
      showToaster("ERROR: Please Logout and Login again.");
    }

    let eventData = null;
    await googleEventCreaterAPI(JSON.stringify(event), provider_token).then(async res=>{
      console.log(res.data);
      eventData = res.data;
    }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

and here I have two console.log
1st console.log

```
{
    "summary": "ShopOnLive Meeting",
    "description": "I want to buy something.",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2023-04-21T14:33:00.000Z",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Calcutta"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2023-04-21T15:13:00.000Z",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Calcutta"
    },
    "conferenceDataVersion": 1,
    "conferenceData": {
        "createRequest": {
            "requestId": "meet-dk8ncv",
            "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                "type": "hangoutsMeet"
            }
        }
    },
    "organizer": {
        "email": "sumit@shoponline.in"
    },
    "attendees": []
}
```

2nd console log

```
{
    "kind": "calendar#event",
    "etag": "\"3364017758736000\"",
    "id": "q7blnj6j4b4rjvrfu051ssgen4",
    "status": "confirmed",
    "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=cTdibG5qNmo0YjRyanZyZnUwNTFzc2dlbjQgc3VtaXRAc2hvcG9ubGl2ZS5pbg",
    "created": "2023-04-20T16:41:19.000Z",
    "updated": "2023-04-20T16:41:19.368Z",
    "summary": "ShopOnLive Meeting",
    "description": "I want to buy something.",
    "creator": {
        "email": "sumit@shoponlive.in",
        "self": true
    },
    "organizer": {
        "email": "sumit@shoponlive.in",
        "self": true
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2023-04-21T20:03:00+05:30",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2023-04-21T20:43:00+05:30",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata"
    },
    "iCalUID": "q7blnj6j4b4rjvrfu051ssgen4@google.com",
    "sequence": 0,
    "reminders": {
        "useDefault": true
    },
    "eventType": "default"
}
```

Comment: Run [calendar.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/get?apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22primary%22%7D&apix=true), make sure to send the calendar id you are trying to use and check `allowedConferenceSolutionTypes` in your response, do you see `hangoutsMeet`? If yes, can you test with [Try this method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert) and see if that way works? I tried it with the same data in your question and it worked, it generated a Google Meet link.

Comment: Thank you so much @LorenaGomez, Using your method I was able to find out what was the problem here. I added `'conferenceDataVersion': 1` in the payload but that should be in the params. I tried to put that in the params but I tried just for the `PUT` method. But now it is working. Thank you so much again.

Comment: I'm glad to know that it works now. For better visibility, I added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an event with Google Meet link, `conferenceDataVersion` needs to be passed as a parameter, not as a payload. You also have to make sure that the request body has the conference data properties.

**Sample Code:**

```
const calendarId = "###";
const event = {
  start: { dateTime: "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000+09:00" },
  end: { dateTime: "2021-01-01T00:30:00.000+09:00" },
  attendees: [{ email: "###" }],
  conferenceData: {
    createRequest: {
      requestId: "sample123",
      conferenceSolutionKey: { type: "hangoutsMeet" },
    },
  },
  summary: "sample event with Meet link",
  description: "sample description",
};
gapi.client.calendar.events
  .insert({
    calendarId: calendarId,
    conferenceDataVersion: 1,
    resource: event,
  })
  .then((res) => console.log(res.result));
```

**References:**

- [Add video and phone conferences to events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events#conferencing)
- [conferenceData](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#conferenceData)
- [Sample Scripts for Creating New Event with Google Meet Link to Google Calendar using Various Languages](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/94791d48823e9659aa376cf7f0161d9b)