# Google Calendar event is not updating on Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have written code where I am first creating an event on Google Calendar using Google Calendar API in .net and after that I am updating the same created Google event using calendar event id and Google is also returning the success response. But somehow when I am opening the event on the calendar it is not showing the updated event on the calendar.

The code that I am using to update the event is:

```
EventsResource.UpdateRequest request = service.Events.Update(createdEvent, HttpUtility.UrlDecode(calendarId), meetingEventId);
request.SendNotifications = sendNotifications;
    if (isOnlineMeeting)
      request.ConferenceDataVersion = 1;
      Event updatedEvent = request.Execute();
```

Can anyone tell why this is happening?

Comment: if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76149626/17926478) answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Comment: Running into the same issue @Upender Singh did Lorena's answer was of help  in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample you shared, I understand that you're trying to add a video and phone conference to an event. (If this is not the case, please update your question with more information)

In order to create an event with Google Meet link, besides adding the `conferenceDataVersion` parameter, you also have to make sure that the request body has the conference data properties. You can see a few samples [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update#examples) in different programming languages.

If you are using the `UPDATE` method, this always updates the entire event resource, to do a partial update, perform a `GET` followed by an `UPDATE`. The other option to update is using `PATCH`, which will replace existing values with the field values you specify.

## References:

- [Add video and phone conferences to events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events#conferencing)
- [conferenceData](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#conferenceData)
- [Events: update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update)
- [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch)

Comment: Hi lorena the solution that you have shared i am already using it, i have fetched or GET the created google calendar event first then assigned the location information with in it and after that passed that created event object to the Event update method. But this also not resolved the issue. issue remains the same and it is intermittent.

Comment: Are you the organizer of the events that you're updating? Also, are you adding the 'conferenceData' parameter to your request, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76093843/17926478) is an example of how the request should look like.